# Sending mail is correct from localhost.But did not work from internet space(web)

Tags: asp.net, deployment, smtp, umbraco, sendmail

I can send email from localhost.But when I sent an email from **internet space** I encountered a  problem.
Is the problem in website panel?
How can I solve it?

> **System.Net.Mail.SmtpException:** The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. 
>   The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required. 
>   Learn more at at System.Net.Mail.MailCommand.CheckResponse(SmtpStatusCode statusCode, String response) 
>   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.SendMail(MailAddress sender, 
>   MailAddressCollection recipients, 
>   String deliveryNotify, 
>   Boolean allowUnicode, 
>   SmtpFailedRecipientException& exception)

at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)

at Defraz.Movafaqiyat.WebApp.usercontrols.AppCodes.MailHelper.SendMailMessage(String from, 
String to, 
String bcc, 
String cc, 
String subject, 
String body, 
String domainName, 
Boolean isBodyHtml)

**a part of webconfig:**

```
<smtp from="movafaqiyat@gmail.com">
    <network host="smtp.gmail.com" port="587" userName="movafaqiyat@gmail.com" password="mypassword" defaultCredentials="false" enableSsl="true" />
  </smtp>
```

Comment: If I were in your shoes I'd contact hosting provider. It could be some network related issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use port="465" ([Set up POP in mail clients](http://support.google.com/mail/answer/13287?hl=en)) and make sure this port is open on the server you use for sending email.